# how to add the integral with defferent bounds?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

we know that for the equation to remain correct, we must do the same thing for both sides, but here, I did not understand how that works. We added integration for both sides, but with different limits or bounds. How is this possible? please Explain to me this, I am trying to understand integration.

we have

dx = v * dt

then

$\int_{x0}^{x} dx = \int_{t0}^{t} v * dt$

and my second question is:

how from that:

$\int_{sa}^{sa} dw = \int_{sa}^{sb} Fx * dx +  Fy * dy$

to that:

$\int_{sa}^{sb} dw = \int_{xa}^{xb} Fx * dx + \int_{ya}^{yb} Fy * dy$

Comment: It is just about designations. $x = x(t), x_0 = x(t_0)$

Comment: thank you!

what about this:

how from that: 

$\int_{sa}^{sb} dw = \int_{sa}^{sb} Fx * dx +  Fy * dy$

to that:

$\int_{sa}^{sb} dw = \int_{xa}^{xb} Fx * dx + \int_{ya}^{yb} Fy * dy$

Comment: Any physical meaning of this integrals?

Comment: yes,
we have force aplied on an object and moves from point a to point b in 2d:

we want to calculate the work(w) from the point a to point b;       

work = f * r but this in constante force;  so: 

we have dw  = $\vec{F} * \vec{dr}$:     

the w: is the work, r: diplacment F the force:       

then dw = Fx * dx + Fy * dy:        

and here we add the integral to find the w;

Comment: We have the same situation here. Actually this integral is $\int_{t_0}^{t} F_x(x(t))\cdot x'(t) dt$ where we can make substitution and get $\int_{x_0}^{x} F_x(x) dx$

Comment: why $x'(t)$ what is this?

Comment: $dx = x'(t)dt$. When such an integration is performed, actually we integrate over time and then we make substitution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150630/discussion-between-aymen-and-egor-ivanov).

Comment: thank you very much i understand now, but there is a small thing: why dx = x'(t) * dt
Isn't it supposed to be  dx(t) = x'(t) * dt

Comment: Yeah, sure, it is right

Comment: is that true: $\int_{a0}^{a} [3a] da =\int_{b0}^{b} [3a(b)] da(b)$

Comment: Yes, it is just variable substitution